# strcpy not copying char array to char pointer

Tags: arrays, pointers, char, strcpy

```
void processWord(char * word) {

    if(word != NULL) {

        char * temp = word;
        char final[32];
        int index = 0;

        while(*temp) {
            if((*temp >= 65 &&  *temp<=90) || (*temp>=97 && *temp<=122)) {
                final[index++] = toupper(*temp);
            }
            temp++;
        }

        final[index] = '\0';

        strcpy(word, final);
    }
}
```

Try to get ride of non alphabet characters and convert to upper case. Problem is at the strcpy line. Final ends up as what it should be, it just wont copy into word, I get a segmentation fault. I've got the #includes I need and the line works just fine if I swap "word" and "final". Pls help someone <3

Comment: Quite possibly "word" passed in here, is defined like "char word[] ="this is atest"; ? If so, it will be in the read-only segment of memory.

Comment: Ya, could you should how the char * your passing in is being created?